# How to analyze the volatility with GARCH?

Tags: r, garch

How could I use GARCH model to detect if the volatility is constant during all the series(time series)?

I can't do a visual check, I need to detect if the volatility is **constant** using R and GARCH function of `tseries` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the classic Engle test for ARCH effects. The test is implemented as follows (copy from Ch. Brooks, "Introductory Econometrics for Finance").

1. Estimate the model

   $$y_t=\beta_0+x_{1t}\beta_1+...+x_{kt}\beta_k + u_t, \quad t=1,...,T$$
   using OLS and save the residuals $\hat{u}_i$. (If you do not have any explanatory   variables, simply demean $y$.)
2. Square the residuals and estimate the following regression:

   $$\hat{u_t}^2=\gamma_0+\hat{u}_{t-1}^2\gamma_1+\hat{u}_{t-2}^2\gamma_2+...+\hat{u}_{t-q}^2\gamma_q+v_t,$$

   Obtain $R^2$ from this regression.
3. The test statistic, which is defined as $T\cdot R^2$, is distributed as $\chi^2(q)$.
4. The null hypothesis is $\gamma_i=0$, $i=1,\ldots,q,$ against the alternative $\exists j: \gamma_j\neq 0$.

This can be implemented in R as follows. Supposing we have $\hat{u}$, the p-value for the hypothesis is

```
> set.seed(13)
> u<-rnorm(100)
> 1-pchisq(summary(lm(X1~.,data=data.frame(embed(u^2,5))))$r.squared*100,4)
[1] 0.6867667
```

Naturally you will need to decide how many lags to include. Since usually GARCH models use small numbers of lags, some predefined number may entirely appropriate. I would do some MC simulations to determine which works best.

Comment: Amazing! thank you for your answer! one question...can I do it with garch() function or do I have to do it manually as you wrote? so IF the pvalue is ABOVE 0.05 it should means that the volatility is constant? How could I change the number of lags inside the code you wrote?

Comment: Probably you cannot do that with `garch`. The answer to the second question is yes, with the usual caveats of interpreting p-values. The number of lags here is 4. So if your number of lags is $p$, change 4 to $p$ and 5 to $p+1$.

Comment: do you mean that I have to modify (100-4) in (100-p) and (u^2,5) in  (u^2,p+1) ? let me know, where p is the number of lags I use. Thank you really much

Comment: Yes, also do not forget to change the last 4 to `p`. This is an argument to pchisq, which is the number of degrees of freedom of chi square distribution.

Comment: Why the numbers of lags must to be equals to the degrees of freedom?

Comment: This is how the test is constructed. See the original Engle article if you really want more details. This is more or less standard multiple regression result, number of degrees of freedom is related to number of regressors in the regression.

Comment: perfect! I will set p instead of the last 4, thank you so much!

Comment: @Dail, I've checked the original article. There T is the number of observation in the initial regression. I've changed the code accordingly.

Comment: I don't see any changes on the R code. Is it wrong? Are you referring to your explanation?

Comment: Seem no series can pass this test...I tried from 4 to 25 lags of series with 800 values... maybe too few lags?